# Image height defined in mm, not showing up at all

Tags: image, pdf, image-size

An image is not showing up on any browser for me.
I'm pretty sure the 'problem' is I have defined the image's height in mm.
I've defined other object's sizes in mm as well, and they appear to be working just fine.
**Why is it different for the img tag?**

I defined the image's height in mm because the HTML gets converted to a PDF using this library:
http://mpdf1.com/manual/

The PDF is a conversion of a HTMLpage:
http://voorbeeld3.mediaconnexion.nl/generator/htmlrender/?id=2097
The image does not show on the HTMLpage, but it does in the resulting PDF:
http://voorbeeld3.mediaconnexion.nl/generator/?download=2097
(this link should give you a download)

**I'd like to know if there's something I can do to make the image show up in the HTML that would not change the way the image is displayed in the PDF.**

This is the 'mainpage' (it's in dutch):
http://voorbeeld3.mediaconnexion.nl/generator/?view=2097

Comment: The size was specified in **cm** and not in **mm** as you stated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare the dimensions using HTML attributes, only two formats are allowed: a number without units (means pixels) or number with the percent sign. The `mm` unit can only be specified if you use CSS ([works well](http://jsfiddle.net/FBxUA/)).

Comment: Thank you, that explains why it's not showing. 1.8cm is not a valid value.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
<img src="/media/pictures/large/84_hilberink_makelaar.jpg" alt="" height="100%">
```

Intead of:

```
<img src="/media/pictures/large/84_hilberink_makelaar.jpg" alt="" height="1.8cm"/>
```

[image]